# Efficient design to search for objects by multiple parameters with range

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, indexing, in-memory-database

I have a set of objects of the same type in memory and each has multiple immutable `int` properties (but not only them).

I need to find an object there (or multiple) whose properties are in small range near specified values. E.g. `a == 5+-1 && b == 21+-2 && c == 9 && any d`.

What's the best way to store objects so I can efficiently retrieve them like this?

I thought about making `SortedList` for each property and using `BinarySearch` but I have a lot of properties so I would like to have a more generic way instead of so many `SortedLists`.

It's important that the set itself is not immutable: I need an ability to add/remove items.

Is there something like memory db for objects (not just data)?

Comment: Try SortedDictionary<int, object> or SortedDictionary<int, List<object>>

Comment: @jdweng, but then I need like ten dictionaries (1 per property) and also a code to concatenate found results. Very cumbersome!

Comment: Having lots of lists doesn’t make something non-generic. The approach you were considering sounds promising, so go ahead and implement it; not everything is built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on @j_random_hacker's answer a bit: The usual approach to 'estimates of the selectivity' is to build a histogram for the index.  But, you might already intuitively know which criteria is going to yield the smallest initial result set out of "a == 5+-1 && b == 21+-2 && c == 9".  Most likely it is "c == 9" unless there's an exceptionally high number of duplicate values and small universe of potential values for 'c'.

So, a simple analysis of the predicates would be an easy starting point.  Equality conditions are highly likely to be the most selective (exhibit the highest selectivity).

From that point, RDBMS' will conduct a sequential scan of the records in the result set to filter for the remaining predicates.  That's probably your best approach, too.

Or, there's any number of in-memory, small footprint SQL-capable DBMS that will do the heavy lifting for you (eXtremeDB, SQLite, RDM,...  google is your friend) and/or that have lower-level interfaces that won't do all the work for you (still, most) but also won't impose SQL on you.

Answer (score 0):

First, having lots of `SortedList`s is not bad design.  It's essentially the way that all modern RDBMSes solve the same problem.

Further to this: *If there was* a simple, general, close-to-optimally-efficient way to answer such queries, RDBMSes would not bother with the comparatively complicated and slow hack of query plan optimisation: that is, generating large numbers of candidate query plans and then heuristically estimating which one will take the least time to execute.

Admittedly, queries with many joins between tables are what tends to make the space of possible plans huge in practice with RDBMSes, and you don't seem to have those here.  But even with just a single table (set of objects), if there are k fields that can be used for selecting rows (objects), then you could theoretically have k! different indices (`SortedList`s of (key, value) pairs in which the key is some ordered sequence of the k field values, and the value is e.g. a memory pointer to the object) to choose from.  If the outcome of the query is a single object (or alternatively, if the query contains a non-range clause for all k fields) then the index used won't matter -- but in every other case, each index will in general perform differently, so a query planner would need to have accurate estimates of the selectivity of each clause in order to choose the best index to use.